# How can I determine the edition an Oracle session is using?

Tags: oracle

We are using the Edition Based Redefinition feature in some software and as a DBA, I want to be able to determine which edition each given connection is using.  This way, we can be sure all connections to the database are using the correct edition.  How can I tell the edition being used by any given session?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_editions.htm#ADFNS99921

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query V$SESSION and include the column `SESSION_EDITION_ID` which contains the value you are looking for.

The link http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/dynviews_3016.htm#REFRN30223 defines all the column meanings for that dynamic view; I would probably do a query like

```
SELECT SID, USERNAME, SCHEMANAME, OSUSER, 
   PROCESS, MACHINE, TERMINAL, PROGRAM, 
   SESSION_EDITION_ID 
from V$SESSION  
order by SESSION_EDITION_ID;
```

Comment: This returns 400 rows. How do I know which one is the correct one?

Comment: @Superdooperhero -- It depends;  for me it might be adding criteria based on PROGRAM, OSUSER, or SCHEMANAME.  If you have control over the creation of the session, you can use the columns MODULE and ACTION in the query, and when you create a session, invoke `exec DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_MODULE(module_name=>'My_Module', action_name=>'do stuff');` then query for those values.

Comment: The SESSION_EDITION_ID is just a numeric value and does not really show what the requestor asked for. See my answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

To find the ***name*** of the edition a session is using, do following query:

```
select object_name as USED_EDITION, vses.*
from V$SESSION vses
JOIN ALL_OBJECTS AO on AO.object_id = vses.session_edition_id
```

It will show you the name as used in DBA_EDITIONS or in ALL_EDITIONS.